# Turtle Graphics Not appearing in my Mac (High Sierra)

Tags: python, macos, pycharm

I've just started learning Python and I'm following a tutorial whose goal is to create a simple Pong game. The black screen appears but the elements, paddle, and ball, do not appear. I'm using iMac (High Sierra) and PyCharm.

Have any of you experienced this or know the root cause?

Here is some example code:

```
turtlename = turtle.Turtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()

wn.title("Pong")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)


# Main Game Loop
while True:
    wn.update()

# Paddle 1
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0)
```

Comment: It's because you entered an infinite loop before you drew the components. Put the main game loop at the end, instead.

Comment: I understand, but even if I drop all the code like here: http://christianthompson.com/sites/default/files/Pong/pong.py all I get is the same black screen and nothing else.